# Alternative to Semver in the Ruby Ecosystem

Tags: ruby, semantic-versioning

Is there a functioning (i.e., that I can use it with `bundler` and `rubygems`) alternative to **SemVer** within the ruby ecosystem (or even elsewhere)?

My problem with **SemVer** (**MAJOR.MINOR.PATCH**) is that it tries to quantify two incompatible things:

1. change size (**PATCH** -- a small change)
2. backwards compatibility (**MINOR** -- nonbreaking, **MAJOR** -- breaking)

**PATCH** is still quite likely to be a breaking change, though, which makes it sort of equal to **MAJOR** while being less than **MINOR**, and **MINOR** is less than **MAJOR**.
so:

```
  PATCH == MAJOR  && MAJOR > MINOR && MINOR > PATCH
```

This implies that PATCH <> MINOR at the same time, which can never be true.

Ideally, I'd like to have two versioning lines--one based on backward compatibility (e.g. **no breakage, potentially imperceptible breakage (==patches), breakage**) and one based on change size (disregarding backward compatibility), a human-friendly versioning line, if you will. And I'd like to be able to use them simultaneously.

(With pure backward-compatibility based versioning alone, I could go from "hello world" to an operating system as long as the operating system starts by writing "hello world" to the screen.)

E.g.:
If *H* stands for human friendly versioning, and *B* for backward compatibility a backward compatibility based-one, then I'd like to be able to say:

1. **~> H2.0** (==stick to H2.X; if you make a version H3.0 which adds
   200MB of nonbreaking additional functionality, I don't want you to
   download that, but do bring me those nonbreaking improvements you
   make in the H2.0 line)
2. **~> B0.1** (==give me **nonbreaking changes** (3rd column, equivalent
   to Semver's 2nd column) and **potentially imperceptibly breaking**
   changes (2nd column, equivalent to SemVer's 3rd column))

Answer (score 6):

There is no support in rubygems/bundler for having two distinct parallel version numbers, no.

But there's no reason you have to use semver. You just need one version number. Bundler and rubygems will work fine with any version numbers of the form 'x.y.z', or even 'x.y' or 'x.y.z.a.b', where all components are numbers. As far as 'functioning', you can do whatever you want, with one version number. (If you use letters and not just numbers, rubygems might decide it indicates a 'prerelease' version. But if you stick to numbers, you can do whatever you want).

Before semver, many people just incremented the components when they felt like it, when it 'seemed' like a major change, or a smaller change, or a tiny change. You can certainly do that -- or use any other system for determining what single version number to apply --  and the infrastructure will work fine. Your downstream users may or may not appreciate it.

I am not sure if you are misunderstanding semver though. [Semver says](http://semver.org/) that a breaking change *must* be a major version increment. If "PATCH is still quite likely to be a breaking change, though", then you aren't doing semver. A breaking change must be a major version bump, according to semver. This isn't always followed, either because of accidental bugs, or people who don't understand semver, or are unwilling to follow it but want to say they are following it anyway -- but it's what semver says.

In fact, semver says that the version number should be *only* about compatibility, *not* about 'size' of change (whether subjective 'bigness', or bytesize; you seem to be talking about bytesize deltas, I've never seen that interpretation of version numbers before). Backward breaking changes require a major version bump; new features without backward-breaking changes require a minor version bump; otherwise (no new features, no backward-breaking changes; so basically bugfixes or internal refactorings) a patch level bump.  Semver does *not* try to incorporate two incompatible things -- rather it tries to throw out one of them entirely, it throws out the idea that a version number should represent the "size of change", it only represents compatibility. People's resistance to this though, is some of the resistance to semver, true.

I am not sure what you mean by "potentially imperceptibly breaking change". Semver says a breaking change is major version bump, you don't get to call it a patch if it's "potentially imperceptibly breaking", which I guess means only some people will notice it and you're guessing most won't? Semver has no interest in such categories.  Semver does not allow you to release a breaking change in a patch level release because you decide it's "potentially imperceptibly breaking" (maybe you'd like it to?).

Versioning and release management is hard. It's often a balance between pain for the maintainer and pain for the downstream users. I'm skeptical that creating two separate parallel version numbers is going to improve things, rather than just make things even more confusing for anyone.  I don't even understand how you'd implement "I don't want you to download that, but do bring me those nonbreaking improvements you make in the H2.0 line" -- it sounds like you are imagining having not just two version numbers on every release, but actually two entirely different *"lines"* of version numbers?

Okay, I suppose you *could* do that, just be releasing with two different gem names. Widget_H and Widget_B, I guess? Off of two different git branches in your repo, I guess?  I don't know, I have trouble figuring out how your musings could possibly be operationalized into a system, even hypothetically.  It seems like it'll make things awfully confusing for both maintainer and downstream user -- but would just using two different gem names accomplish what you want in the rubygems/bundler ecosystem?

If you haven't read the [semver spec](http://semver.org/), I would highly encourage it, so you understand what semver is and isn't.